# Does first LEFT JOIN apply to multiple JOINs?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have a multiple `JOIN` in the form of

```
SELECT * FROM column1
  LEFT JOIN column2 USING(id)
  JOIN column3 USING(name)
  JOIN column4 USING(info)
  WHERE column1.id = 44
```

If changing the `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`; for obvious reason, the query will return nothing in the absence of column2.id. The main data is column1 and the others are supportive data; thus, I want to retrieve data just if column1.id exists.

My question is: Does the first `LEFT JOIN` guarantees the query to return column1 values where column1.id exists, regardless of subsequent `JOIN`s (e.g. when column3.name does not exist)? Or I need to change the next (all) `JOIN`s to `LEFT JOIN` too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options as the direct answer to your question is `no`.

Change all subsequent joins to LEFT JOINs.

```
SELECT * FROM column1
  LEFT JOIN column2 USING(id)
  LEFT JOIN column3 USING(name)
  LEFT JOIN column4 USING(info)
  WHERE column1.id = 44
```

If possible, re-arrange the query...

```
SELECT * FROM column1
  JOIN column3 USING(name)
  JOIN column4 USING(info)
  LEFT JOIN column2 USING(id)
  WHERE column1.id = 44
```

Or...

```
SELECT * FROM column1
  JOIN
  (
       column3
  JOIN column4 USING(info)
  LEFT JOIN column2 USING(id)
  )
    USING(name)
  WHERE column1.id = 44
```

On a side note, I'd avoid natural joins and the `USING` syntax.  The logic is less transparent, it's more open to bugs, more open to break later (if you add a field to one of the tables duplicating a field in the USING option), etc, etc.

Comment: re-arranging is not useful, as the missing part can be in any column. For example, column3.name can be absent which will affect the query to return nothing. P.S. Thanks for the side note! I know that `USING` can be subject to confusion and not favorable, but I don't know why I like it :)

Answer (score 1):

They "chain together" so they should all be left joins.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the `left`s.

Every JOIN will try to join the results form previous joins to the next table.

You can think the query like this:

```
  ((column1
    LEFT JOIN column2 USING(id)
    )
  JOIN column3 USING(name)
  )
  JOIN column4 USING(info)
  WHERE column1.id = 44
```